# Can't pass parameters to function from WxPython Menu Item

Tags: python, wxpython

I'm having trouble getting sensible output when I try to bind menu buttons to a function. First, I pass a few items to create a menu in my application:

```
imported_applications = ["foo", "bar"]

application_menu = wx.Menu()

for app in imported_applications:
    # Create Items
    item = wx.MenuItem(application_menu, wx.ID_ANY, app, )
    application_menu.Append(item)

    # Bind to function
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.select_application, item, id=app)

# Add to menubar
menubar.Append(application_menu, '&Applications')

self.SetMenuBar(menubar)
```

Then I try to get that parameter when select_application is called:

```
def select_application(self, event):

    id_selected = event.GetId()
    print(id_selected)
```

Outputs:

```
-2014
-2015
```

**Not sure where that is coming from but I expect it to output the id that I set at `bind`. The contents of imported_applications are two strings, i.e. ["foo", "bar]**

Comment: an "ID" in wxPython is an integer and not some string, so you could do APPID = wx.ID_ANY to get a unique ID to be used with your menu.  You might also want to look at the menu demo in the wxPython demo.

Comment: another info source is http://www.wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/Menu.html , that is the doc for wxPython Phoenix but most of it applies also for wxPython classic, which is what you are probably using.

Answer (score 0):

```
app = [ "foo", "bar", ]
for app in ...
```

Here, your **app** variable is overwritten.

Comment: sorry, that was a typo from when I added it on here as an example. Should be `imported_applications`.

Answer (score 0):

You are not appending the items correctly.The `wx.Menu` requires other parameters to its `Append` method. You should be receiving an error if you run that code as-is. Instead, you'll want to use `AppendItem`. If you want the menu's label to be printed in the event handler, then you'll have to extraxt the id from the event and use that to acquire the label's text. Here is a demo that does just that:

```
import wx

class MyForm(wx.Frame):

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, "wx.Menu Tutorial")

        # Add a panel so it looks the correct on all platforms
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY)

        menuBar = wx.MenuBar()
        fileMenu = wx.Menu()

        imported_applications = ["foo", "bar"]
        for item in imported_applications:
            item = wx.MenuItem(fileMenu, wx.ID_ANY, item)
            fileMenu.AppendItem(item)
            self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.onMenuPress, item)

        menuBar.Append(fileMenu, "&File")

        self.SetMenuBar(menuBar)

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def onMenuPress(self, event):
        """"""
        menu_id = event.GetId()
        obj = event.GetEventObject()
        menu_label = obj.GetLabelText(menu_id)
        print menu_label

# Run the program
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyForm().Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```